# How to embedd resources to compiled source code correctly?

Tags: c#, bitmap, compilation, embedded-resource

I want to compile some code and add some resources with CodeDom Provider. My problem is to add the resources correctly, so that I can use them in another project after compiling.
I add the resource (a bitmap) by the method of `CompilerParameters()`.

```
EmbeddedResources.Add(bitmap)
```

After compiling I decompile the `.dll` with ILSpy you can see, that the bitmap was added as an embedded Resource in the folder Resource to the project.
Now I want to use this resource in another project by

```
try
{
    Assembly resourceAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pathofthefirstdassembly);
    Stream stream = resourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceAssembly.GetName().Name + ".Bitmap3.bmp");
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
catch (MissingManifestResourceException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Mistakes: " + ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Everytime I want to do this, the program stops and it says that the stream is null.

How can I fix this problem or how am I able to use resources from a compiled `.dll` I just added the resource to?